# A problem about how to understand the existence of derivative of level set in Mountain-pass theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I'm confused about the Mountain pass theorem in Lemma4 of [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00229-010-0365-1).

**Background :**

$$
\begin{gathered}
I_\lambda(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_M\left|\Delta_g^{\frac{m}{2}} u\right|^2 d \mu_g-\frac{\lambda}{2 m} \log \left(\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g\right) \\
\text { in } E:=\left\{u \in H^m(M): \int_M u d \mu_g=0\right\} \text { with the norm }\|u\|:=\left(\int_M\left|\Delta_g^{\frac{m}{2}} u\right|^2 d \mu_g\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} .
\end{gathered}
$$

Now they have already found

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\|u_\sigma\right\| & =\left(2 \Lambda_1+o(1)\right) \log \sigma, \\
I_\lambda\left(u_\sigma\right) & =\left(\Lambda_1-\lambda+o(1)\right) \log \sigma.
\end{aligned}
$$

After some calculations, if we fix $\lambda \in\left(\Lambda_1, \lambda_1 / 2 m\right)$ ($\lambda_1 $ is the first eigenvalue of $(-\Delta_g)^{m}$), the energy functional is not bounded below and 0 is the strict minimum of the energy functional (which creates a crater). Besides, there exists $\sigma=\sigma(\lambda)>0$ such that for $u_0:=u_\sigma$ we have
$$
I\left(u_0\right)<0 \text { and }\left\|u_0\right\| \geq 1 .
$$

**Paths:**
$$
P:=\left\{\gamma \in C^0([0,1] ; E): \gamma(0)=0, \gamma(1)=u_0, \gamma(t) \in C^{\infty}(M) \text { for } 0 \leq t \leq 1\right\},
$$
and define
$$
c_\mu:=\inf _{\gamma \in P} \max _{t \in[0,1]} I_\mu(\gamma(t)),
$$
Since by Jensen's inequality $\log \left(\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g\right) \geq \log \left(e^{\int_M 2 m u d \mu_g}\right) \geq 0$, the function $\mu \mapsto c_\mu$ is nonincreasing, hence differentiable for almost every $\mu \in$ $\left(\lambda, \lambda_1 / 2 m\right)$, which used the so called Monotone differentiation theorem.

**I'm confused about the meaning of **$c_\mu^{\prime}$ exists.** They proved that when **$c_\mu^{\prime}$ exists.**, the P-S condition is satisfied, but I don't know where they used this condition.**

They proved by contradiction, suppose for each $C_0>0$ there exists $\delta\left(C_0\right)>$ 0 for which $\|u\|^2 \leq C_0$ and $\left|I_\mu(u)-c_\mu\right|<2 \delta$ imply $\left\|I_\mu^{\prime}(u)\right\| \geq 2 \delta$. We set $\alpha:=-c_\mu^{\prime}+3 \geq 3$ (Since by Jensen's inequality $\log \left(\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g\right)>0$, the function $\mu \mapsto c_\mu$ is nonincreasing), we consider a decreasing sequence $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ and a sequence of paths $$\gamma_n \in P:=\left\{\gamma \in C^0([0,1] ; E): \gamma(0)=0, \gamma(1)=u_0, \gamma(t) \in C^{\infty}(M)\right. \text{for} \left.0 \leq t \leq 1\right\}$$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{saddle1}
\max _{0 \leq t \leq 1} I_\mu\left(\gamma_n(t)\right) \leq c_\mu+\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)
\end{equation}

Take $v_n=\gamma_n\left(t_n\right)$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{saddle2}
I_{\mu_n}\left(v_n\right) \geq c_{\mu_n}-2\left(\mu_n-\mu\right) .
\end{equation}

In particular
$$
I_\mu\left(v_n\right)-I_{\mu_n}\left(v_n\right) \leq c_\mu+\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)-\left(c_\mu-\alpha\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)\right)=(\alpha+1)\left(\mu_n-\mu\right),
$$
so that
$$\tag{1}
\frac{I_\mu\left(v_n\right)-I_{\mu_n}\left(v_n\right)}{\mu_n-\mu}=\frac{1}{2 m} \log \left(\int_M e^{2 m v_n} d \mu_g\right) \leq \alpha+1 .
$$

Do these steps need the existence of $c_\mu^{\prime}$? Since we need to make $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$, so the problem may happen in (1), but can the existence of $c_\mu^{\prime}$ avoid the problem in (1) when $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$? In fact, if we fixed $u$, $$
I_\lambda(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_M\left|\Delta_g^{\frac{m}{2}} u\right|^2 d \mu_g-\frac{\lambda}{2 m} \log \left(\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g\right)
$$
is also non-increasing, why don't they require the existence of $\frac{dI_{\lambda}}{d\lambda}$?

Comment: For the final sentence: $I_\lambda$ is linear in $\lambda$, so its derivative with respect to $\lambda$ always exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! They used a test function $\varphi_n(u):=\varphi\left(\frac{I_{\mu_n}(u)-c_\mu}{\mu_n-\mu}\right)$, where $c_\mu:=\inf _{\gamma \in P} \max _{t \in[0,1]} I_\mu(\gamma(t))$, maybe the well-definedness of this function needs the existence  of $c_\mu^{\prime}$?